# Remove DMCA removal notice from Google search results

Tags: google, duplicate-content, dmca

I found a webpage which merely copied my blog entry, so I submitted a DMCA notice to Google. The notice was accepted and the page was removed from the Google search. This happened a couple of weeks ago.

But I still see the following message for the Google search results:

> *In response to a complaint we received under the US Digital Millennium Copyright Act, we have removed 1 result(s) from this page. If you wish, you may read the DMCA complaint that caused the removal(s) at LumenDatabase.org.*

Does anyone know how long this will stay? Or is there anyway to remove it, so that I can even erase the trace of the fact that I submitted the DMCA notice?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely still under review by Googles Search Quality Evaluators.

When a  valid DCMA violation/takedown notice gets submitted, Google's internal teams review it for completeness and check for other problems.

Once that process is complete, it will be removed from Google's indices and you will likely receive communication from Google. The notice will appear in the search results until this occurs.

Please review Google's official [Transparency Report](https://transparencyreport.google.com/copyright/overview?hl=en) for more detailed information on this issue.

---

### Quick SEO Tip:

In the future if this happens to you again I would first reach out to the webmaster/site owner of the site that copied your content and ask that they edit the page on their site to list your page URL as the `Canonical URL`

In addition, you can ask that they credit you as the author and/or provide a backlink to your website. There is *a lot* of SEO value you can gain from this situation.

If they refuse, of course then yes proceed with a DCMA complaint, you don't want a duplicate indexed that will hurt your organic visibility. Unless of course the reason for issuing the DCMA was for other legal reasons.

Learn more: [Using the Cross Domain Rel=Canonical to Maximize the SEO Value of Cross-Posted Content](https://moz.com/blog/cross-domain-rel-canonical-seo-value-cross-posted-content)